What comic character is this in the Marvel intro for the first episode of Ms. Marvel?
What comic character is featured in this frame of the Marvel intro from episode 1 of Ms. Marvel?


Looks like the frame is in Loki as well, so probably not Ms. Marvel directly.
https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/1382a60f-fbaa-45ef-8f81-7f8ab02f55ea

The first time he appeared in the intro was in Thor: Dark World, 2013, iirc
